# Puppeteer - unable to perform action on a selector when run on Jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to test the login page of my application. 
The below code runs fine on my local system but when run on Jenkins 9 times out of 10, I get error (mentioned below).

I have tried different things to fix this but haven't been successful. Also added setTimeOut but even that doesn't help to fix this.

Here is the sample code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const CREDS = require('../creds');

describe('Login & Title', () => {
  var browser, page;
  var url = 'https://www.example.com/login'

beforeEach (async () => {
      browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: true
});

      page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(url);

    })

afterEach (() => {
    browser.close()
  })

test('Test for Page Title', async () => {
    var millisecondsToWait = 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
    }, millisecondsToWait);

    const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#inputUserName';
    const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#inputPassword';
    const BUTTON_SELECTOR = 'body > div > ng-view > form > div:nth-child(3) > button';

    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);

    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    const title = await page.title();
    expect(title).toBe("Example Website");
  });
})
```

I am getting error:

```
console.assert node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:597
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: No node found for selector: #inputUserName

FAIL __tests__/login.test.js
  Login & Title
    ✕ Test for Page Title (513ms)

  ● Login & Title functionality.. › Test for Page Title

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

      at Frame.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:598:18)
```

Any pointers or help would be great! Thanks in Advance.